# Is there a word that means "talking while your mouth is full of liquid"?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word that means "talking while your mouth is full of liquid"? Like, for instance, you can speak while you are drowning in your own blood making it hard to make out what you are saying. I am wondering if there's a word for that.

For example:

> He ____ "I love you" while he was drowning in his blood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One word for this could be to **gurgle**.

Also, check out [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/225955/is-there-a-verb-that-describes-speaking-with-a-full-mouth#answer-295351) on ELU. It pertains to a verb for speaking with your mouth full but many of the examples in the answers for that question are also usable for your scenario. The link here goes directly to an answer which suggests **sputter**.